# disable draggable function for particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

crop_popup_box

```
<div id="crop_box" class="popup_box crop_popup">
<span class="popup-title" id="popup_title">Crop Image</span>    
<div id="crop_div" style="display:none;">
    <div style="margin-left:60px;" class="example">
        <div class="default">
            <div  class="cropMain"><div class="crop-container" style="width: 320px; height: 320px;"><div class="crop-overlay" style="z-index: 6000; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div><img class="crop-img" src="./jQuery & Canvas Image Cropper_files/one.jpg" style="z-index: 5999; top: -149.8px; left: -622.6650049850448px; width: 1402.7676969092722px; height: 549.6px;"></div></div>

            <div class="cropSlider horizontal"><a style="left: 43%; z-index: 1;"><div class=""></div></a><input type="hidden" name="" value="2.29"></div>

        </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

script.js

```
 $(function() {
        $( ".popup_box" ).draggable();         
  });
```

I had applied draggable property to this crop popup.I am able to drag the entire popup.Is it possible to restrict the draggable function for class `cropSlider horizontal` in div.If the use click on `div cropSlider horizontal` and drag the popup should not get drag,because i am using a zoom bar in that div.While using the zoom bar the popup gets dragging and not able to zoom the image.

I tried this,

```
$('div.cropSlider').draggable( "disable" )
```

It is not working.Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also disable later on, when required:

```
$('div.cropSlider').draggable();  
$('div.cropSlider').draggable( "option", "disabled", true );
```

Comment: Tried this but not working,dragging is working on from cropSlider class

Comment: The problem is this  cropSlider div is inside a popup div with class  popup_box,and this div is draggable. So what i am excepting is when user click on that particular portion(div.cropSlider) the whole popup should not be draggable.Is it possible

Comment: This is what i required.Working great.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$('.popup_box div.cropSlider').draggable({disabled: true});
```

Comment: Tried this but not working,dragging is working on from cropSlider class

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$(".popup_box").children('.cropSlider').draggable({disabled:true});
```

Comment: Tried this but not working,dragging is working on from cropSlider class